# What is new about the "new" Magic Mouse as of August 2021?

Tags: mac, mouse

The [Magic Mouse is currently marked](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK2E3AM/A/magic-mouse) on Apple.com as being “new”. I do not recall any news stories about the mouse having changed.

➥ What is new about it?

And what is the model number to identify these newer ones?

[image: screenshot of new Magic Mouse]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updates

1. Includes woven USB-C-to-Lightning cable (vs. USB-to-Lightning)
2. Longer battery life

[CNET](https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/apples-latest-magic-keyboard-mouse-and-touchpad-are-now-available-to-buy-separately/):

> Each Magic accessory comes with a USB-C-to-Lightning cable so you can
> charge it from your Mac, which Apple says you'll only need to do every
> month or so.

[Apple](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK2E3AM/A/magic-mouse):

> The incredibly long-lasting internal battery will power your Magic
> Mouse for about a month or more between charges. It’s ready to go
> right out of the box and pairs automatically with your Mac, and it
> includes a woven USB-C to Lightning Cable that lets you pair and
> charge by connecting to a USB-C port on your Mac.

## <s>Model</s> Order #

Update: as pointed out by [@Gilby](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/43889/gilby), the number below is not the model #. I wasn’t able to find the model # listed online.

Based on the Apple URL, the <s>model</s> order # seems to be:

```
MK2E3AM/A
```

## Release Date

The release date seems to be August 3rd, 2021 - given that this is when [MacRumors spotted the updated accessories](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/08/03/apple-magic-keyboard-touch-id-purchase/) for sale. It seems like Apple didn’t formally announce the release, instead quietly listing the updated items for sale on their store.

Comment: Strictly, that is not the 'model' number, that is the 'order' number (which may vary slightly by country).  The model number is something like A1657 which is the model number for Magic Mouse 2 introduced in 2015. Do you have the model number?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that @Gilby. I’ve updated the answer.