# New Magic accessories

Tags: mac, magic-trackpad, magic-keyboard-ipad

Does anyone know if they updated the Bluetooth chipset in the Aug '21 magic accessories update?

BT3.0+EDR isn't cutting it. I get choppy, laggy mouse movements on a clean install. It's a bit annoying.

I didn't see anything about the BT chipset here:
[What is new about the "new" Magic Mouse as of August 2021?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425313/what-is-new-about-the-new-magic-mouse-as-of-august-2021)

Just a higher capacity battery, but if they updated that, maybe they updated the BT chipset too.

Comment: Only somewhat related: make sure you troubleshoot your BT issue. The connection issue is often caused by a dongle or cable connected to the Mac or an object physically inbetween the Mac and the peripheral.

Comment: I've tried, my late-2013 macbook pro is 15 inches from my mouse. The lag comes and goes, and is very annoying. It happens on a fresh install of every OSX/MacOS since I got this Magic Mouse 2 new in 2015. I also have issues with my BT5.0 headset when I use it with my MBP, so the issue is likely tied to the Laptop. But I was hoping for more than BT3.0 on the updated mouse.